# Let $B$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint intervals $[a_i,b_i)$ where $a_i\in\Bbb R$ and $b_i\in\Bbb Q$. Can $B$ be uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an exercise I am trying to solve the following question appeared:

> Let $A_i$ denote the following interval: $[a_i,b_i) \subset \mathbb R$, with $a_i \in \mathbb R$ and $b_i \in \mathbb Q$. Let $B := \{A_i \subset \mathbb R$, such that if $\forall A_i,A_j \in B,$ then $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$$\}$. Is the set $B$ countable or uncountable?

Without that final restriction it would be easy to prove that this set is uncountable because we would have: $B \sim \mathbb R \times \mathbb Q$, but I don't even know how to approach the problem due to that restriction. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to be careful how to define $B$, not in terms of itself. Do you mean $B:=\{A_i:\forall j\ne i, A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset\}$?

Comment: The title is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick a rational number $r_i \in A_i$ for each $i$ and show that $A_i \to r_i$ is injective.